# Change of Variables in Infinitesimal Generator

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have a random process $\chi$, which has infinitesimal generator

$$\mathcal{L} = A\bigg(\chi^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \chi^2}+\chi\frac{\partial}{\partial \chi}\bigg), \quad A\in\mathbb{R}.$$

I want to find however, the generator of $|\chi|^2$. I am having trouble finding this. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: In principle you just use Ito's formula but the difficulty is to write everything in terms of the post-changed variable after you are done.

Comment: To obtain the generator I converted my SDE in Stratonovich form into Ito form. I'm not sure how applying Ito's formula would help here.

Comment: I'm saying that you want to apply Ito's formula to $f(x)=x^2$, which essentially furnishes the generator of $x^2$ but it doesn't actually write things in terms of $x^2$. The step after that, writing things in terms of $x^2$, requires $x^2$ to actually be Markov so that it has a semigroup at all, and it's not totally obvious to me that that is the case here without actually doing the calculation with Ito's formula.

Comment: I see. That's interesting.